# Why $\log(1/z) = -\log(z)$ is true for $- \pi < \arg(z) < \pi $ and it's false for $0 < \arg(z) < 2 \pi$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, branch-cuts

I don't underestand why this argument is false:

We take 
$$z = re^{i\theta}.$$

Then
$$\log(z^{-1}) = \log(r^{-1}e^{-i\theta}) = -\log(r) - i\theta = -\log(re^{i\theta}) = -\log(z).$$

And why it only works when we take the branch-cut on $- \pi < \arg(z) < \pi $?

Comment: Just to see it quickly notice that in the $(0,2\pi)$ version you have $\log(i)=(\pi/2) i$ and $\log(1/i)=(3\pi/2)i$.

Comment: Indeed the multiplication identity only holds at the level of log as a multi valued function, in general for a particular branch cut the two sides can differ by a multiple of $2\pi i$.

Comment: Ian has it: in general over complex numbers, the best we can say is that $\log(ab) = \log a + \log b + 2k\pi i$ for some integer $k$.